# Monsieur Durand a-t-il un prénom?

Tags: expressions, société, prénoms, noms-de-famille

Dans les pays anglophones, l'homme de la rue (« Monsieur Tout-le-monde ») sera l'objet d'une personnalisation sous le nom de **John Smith** (considéré comme le nom le plus répandu). En français, il semble que ce même personnage peu remarquable soit **M. Durand**, ou **M. Dupont**. Mais, contrairement à l'anglais, je ne crois pas avoir jamais entendu de prénom associé à ce nom. En existe-t-il ? Et dans des pays francophones autres que la France, ou dans des régions françaises, a-t-il un autre nom ?

Comment: Il y a aussi John Doe qui est utilisé : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe

Comment: @Scorpi0 j'ai modifié la question pour être plus clair. John Smith, c'est « Monsieur Tout-le-mode », alors que John Doe, c'est un anonyme : soit parce que son identité est inconnue (les cadavres « John Doe » dans les séries policières), soit parce que son identité est protégée (les affaires de justices « X vs. Doe »).

Comment: En lisant Wikipédia, il y a pourtant les deux possibilités : soit un anonyme, soit un monsieur lambda. Après, étant francophone, je n'en sais pas plus, peut être que Wikipédia se trompe :)

Comment: Monsieur Durand, c'est Machin, non?

Comment: Il y a aussi « Madame Michu ».

Comment: Don't forget "Tom, Dick, and Harry" or, nowadays, "Joe the Plumber".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En France, on parle effectivement de *M. Durand* ou de *M. Dupont* mais aussi de *M. Martin*, de *M. Lambda* et de *M. Tartempion*. Tous ont la même signification, et curieusement,

- *M. Tartempion* relève d'un langage plus familier que les quatre autres
- *M. Lambda* me semble (je dis bien me semble) relever d'un langage un peu plus soutenu. Peut-être car Lambda n'est pas réellement un nom mais une lettre grecque.

Et aucun n'a de prénom **consacré** (ce qui n'interdit pas d'en utiliser un de temps à autres). Peut-être car cette absence de prénom contribue au côté impersonnel de cette expression.

Answer (score 9):

La page wikipedia sur [l'homme de la rue](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homme_de_la_rue) résume bien la situation en listant les nombreuses possibilités. La plupart des noms y sont mentionnés sans prénom, à l'exception du *'ti Joe* des Acadiens du Nouveau-Brunswick (paraît-il).

Par contre, on peut voir plus loin sur la page que *Jean Dupont* ou *Paul Martin* sont utilisés en France. En général, je pense que Jean, Pierre et Paul sont les prénoms bateau les plus courants.

Comment: Ah oui, Mme Michu, c'et vrai! Et M. X aussi... et Duchemol... +1 !

Comment: +1 pour *Jean Dupont*, le seul que je connaisse.

Answer (score 8):

Au Québec on emploie parfois la suite de prénoms "Pierre, Jean, Jacques" pour dire *n'importe qui* ou *Monsieur Tout-le-monde*.

Comment: En France on utilise "Pierre, Paul, Jacques".

Answer (score 3):

A ma connaissance, il n'y a pas de prénom particulier associé à M. Durand ou M. Dupont.

Lorsqu'un prénom est nécessaire au contexte, on utilise alors souvent un prénom classique en France, tel que *Pierre*, *Paul* ou *Jean*.